# Maps SDK Location works only after opening Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I've noticed a very strange but reproducible bug when testing my app, which uses `play-services-maps:11.6.2` and `play-services-location:11.6.2`.

The app uses an Embedded map, and when opened it won't show any location (even after the location permission has been granted).

This happens only when the app `Google Maps` has never been opened.

After opening `Google Maps` and granting permission to the app, the location will work on the Android Map SDK in my app too.
This is reproducible on different Samsung and Sony devices.

Did anyone else experience anything like that?

Comment: show us code relevant to getting user permission , what permissions are you getting? and how and what client have you implemented as a location source

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding, You can add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
```

Comment: that is not the case

Comment: @SharartiKAKA During My implementation I realize same issue as above so I change this Gradle and It was working very fine

Comment: so you are saying that issue solved by downgrading the dependencies

Comment: @SharartiKAKA yes In my case that worked fine so I posted

Comment: ok. But I have implemented with the 11.0 and 11.2 both dependencies worked fine even on mentioned devices